# Error loading DLL - Console App - Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: c#, dll, c#-5.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to load a third-party DLL in a Console App project created in Visual Studio Community 2022. Environment is Windows 10. I have tried both .NET 5.0 and 6.0

No matter what I have tried, I get the error "Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL format. The format of the file  is invalid."

I have checked and normally this error is because I'm trying to load a x64 DLL in a x86 app or viceversa, but I know this is not the case because:

- I have been able to load this specific DLL in C (using LoadLibrary() in Codeblocks) and JAVA (using JNA), configuring the applications for a x86 target platform. I have configured this console app for a x86 target platform as well in properties.
- The DLL when loaded starts writing to a log file. The log file destination is fixed, and can't be deactivated. Whenever I run my app, I see the log being written to. I realized that the log was being written to by using Sysinternals' Process Monitor.

The log only says

> INFO:   2.23.00 12:14:27(00000015)       PCLService.cpp:138    [22.11.2021]    logCreate

> INFO:   2.23.00 12:14:27(00000000)       PCLService.cpp:141    PDA_Manager: DllMain attached

> INFO:   2.23.00 12:14:27(00000000)       PCLService.cpp:145    PDA_Manager: DllMain detach

Normally, the detach should only happen when the DLL is unloaded/program is closed. Here it happens automatically. It is like the program can't keep the DLL loaded, giving the error message.

Here is my current code.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Documentacion\VisaNet\Proyectos\Simpler\bin\Debug\x86\PCLService.dll");
            var DLL = Assembly.LoadFrom("PCLService.dll");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried both LoadFrom() and LoadFile(). Even tried Load(), but the error is different about additional information that I don't know how to get.

I have checked Assembly Binding Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe) and Process Monitor. I do not see any obvious problem.

[image: Process Monitor screenshot]

I assume that whatever error happens, it did happen by the time of the last 4 entries about PCLService.log, which must the ones writing in the DLL log about detaching, because there are no more entries about the log in Process Monitor.

While I'm a experienced programmer, I'm totally new to Visual Studio / C#

Any assistance would be welcome.

Comment: Assembly.LoadFrom() can only be used to load a .NET assembly.  "PCLService.cpp" gives a very strong hint that this DLL is not such an assembly, C++ normally generates a native DLL that is only usable from C# with [DllImport].  And you'll get BadImageFormatException for such a DLL.

Comment: For whatever reason, whenever I searched "load DLL in C#" I ended up with results about assembly. As I said, I'm new for C#, so I while I figured it wasn't the same, I wasn't shown alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a native dll, you have to use `[DllImport]` together with a function prototype. Any of the `Assembly.LoadXXX()` methods are for managed libraries only. Maybe [Using a 32bit or 64bit dll in C# DllImport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852634/using-a-32bit-or-64bit-dll-in-c-sharp-dllimport) will help you.

Comment: Hi! I just tested, and it seems to work. Many thanks.

Does it work on C# 6.0 as well? Or it is a different method?

Comment: @DavidAñez This concept works on any version of C# down to 1.0.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I intended to use what I see is called 'top level statements', which seems to be for .NET 6.0, so C# 10.0? So I wonder how to use DllImport in that environment, or if there is an equivalent way.

Comment: @DavidAñez Top level statements can be used I think from C# 9.0 onwards. However, that is only a shortcut to write the `Main` method and is completely independent of this problem here. In this case, you should create a (static) class containing all the function prototypes you need for that library.