# Expression Blend doesn't recognise any Controls anymore

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I have a VS project with several XAML designed windows and user controls. A while ago they still opened fine in Blend 5, but recently (don't know what changed) it doesn't want to load any file anymore. On loading even the simplest window, it gives lots of errors like:

```
> UserControl is not supported in windows presentation foundation.

> Window is not supported in windows presentation foundation

> Slider is not supported in windows presentation foundation
```

etcetera. Which is obviously silly, as these are very basic components of WPF. Also, in Visual Studio (2012) the windows load absolutely fine.

I did find this [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174621/blend-window-is-not-supported-in-a-wpf-project), so I ensured that my project set-up has indeed an `AnyCPU` set-up. It has this:

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

So that seems all right. The project does have dependencies on other projects in the solution, but it seems like they're all in place, as the programme just runs (though I'm not sure how I could check this to be sure).

What else could have gone wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?